# Solution for Parent/Child circular references: WeakReference class

Tags: object-oriented, vba, weak-references

Sometimes in advanced OOP scenarios, a class needs to hold instances of another class which needs to hold a reference to the "parent". For example when you have a dynamic `UserForm` control that needs to "call back" to the parent form that created it, or when you have a `ViewAdapter` that talks to some UI, which in turn needs to "call back" to the adapter.

Such relationships create *circular references*, and if nothing is done to solve this, the objects don't get cleaned up and you're looking at what's essentially a memory leak.

With the help of [Comintern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36565/comintern) I've written a class that solves this problem, and called it `WeakReference` - in order to make the API as simple to use as possible, I wrapped it with an `IWeakReference` interface:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IWeakReference"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Object() As Object
End Property
```

Here's the `WeakReference` class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "WeakReference"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Implements IWeakReference

#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
#Else
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
#End If

Private Type TReference
    Address As Long
End Type

Private this As TReference

Public Function Create(ByVal instance As Object) As IWeakReference
    With New WeakReference
        .Address = ObjPtr(instance)
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As IWeakReference
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Address() As Long
    Address = this.Address
End Property

Public Property Let Address(ByVal value As Long)
    this.Address = value
End Property

Private Property Get IWeakReference_Object() As Object
    ' Bruce McKinney's code for getting an Object from the object pointer:
    Dim objT As Object
    CopyMemory objT, this.Address, 4
    Set IWeakReference_Object = objT
    CopyMemory objT, 0&, 4
End Property
```

Can this class be improved? Is the interface & factory method overkill?

---

Here's a simple example usage scenario:

Class: `TheParent`

```
Option Explicit

Private child As TheChild

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set child = New TheChild
    Set child.Parent = Me
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set child = Nothing
End Sub
```

And the `TheChild` class:

```
Option Explicit

Private ref As IWeakReference

Public Property Get Parent() As TheParent
    Set Parent = ref.Object
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal value As TheParent)
    Set ref = WeakReference.Create(value)
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Stop ' expected break here when TheParent is terminated
    Set ref = Nothing
End Sub
```

And a little procedure to test everything:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim p As TheParent
    Set p = New TheParent
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(p)
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

As expected, the `Stop` statement is hit in `TheChild`, and if you put a breakpoint in `TheParent`'s `Class_Terminate` handler, it's also hit - whereas if you replace the `IWeakReference` with `TheParent` in `TheChild`, none of the two `Class_Terminate` handlers run.

Comment: VBA doesn't have proper garbage collection?

Comment: @cHao VBA isn't garbage-collected, it's reference-counted. Circular references are also a problem in garbage-collected languages (AFAIK).

Comment: Credit should really go to Bruce McKinney, not me. His code, my memory. ;-)

Comment: Please don't hard-code the size... *ever*. `LenB` is to VBA what `sizeof` is to C. Use it to size the allocation for the copy memory API.

Comment: @this that's answer material right there ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Circular references are more a problem in reference-counted scenarios. Any decent GC will handle them easily, but can only clean them up once both objects are unreachable.

Comment: @cHao By that logic, VBA must not have a decent GC.  ;-)

Comment: @Comintern: Apparently :)

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-WeakReference. Looks to be safe to use even if the pointer is not valid anymore as opposed to the solution presented by TinMan

Comment: @JoeD the sad part is that my blog article was unlicensed, the code in this post is under CC-BY-SA, and this guy grabs my stuff and licenses it under GPLv3. I wouldn't mind MIT, but there's something like a mild copyright violation going on here. I've posted [this issue](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-WeakReference/issues/1) to warmly recommend relicensing to MIT.

Comment: Just wondering, you say you use the `IWeakReference` interface to simplify the API, the client never interacts with a `WeakReference` directly, other than as a constructor. Why then do you expose a `Property Get` for the Address if that member is only ever required during construction, so shouldn't be accessed afterwards? And what arguments might there be for and against making the `IWeakReference` with no Let/Set member - why make the class immutable?

Comment: Also if you are going to create a class with a constructor then use an interface to hide the constructor's inner workings for a simpler "view" of the class, why not just simplify the class itself and use a factory method? 2 modules either way

Comment: @Greedo somehow a mutable weak reference didn't strike me as a good idea... I always make the class expose get+let, then the interface only exposes the getter. The public Let member is needed for the factory method to make the initial assignment, and it's mutability that needs justifications ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazing code as always, Mathieu and Comintern; many thanks.

I'm here only to add two cents:

Probably you tested it in a 32 bits setup; to compile in a 64 bits you need to (only differences):

```
    #If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
    Private Type TReference
        Address As LongPtr
    End Type
    #Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
    Private Type TReference
        Address As Long
    End Type
    #End If
         ...
    #If Win64 Then
    Public Property Get Address() As LongPtr
        Address = this.Address
    End Property
    Public Property Let Address(ByVal value As LongPtr)
        this.Address = value
    End Property
    #Else
    Public Property Get Address() As Long
        Address = this.Address
    End Property
    Public Property Let Address(ByVal value As Long)
        this.Address = value
    End Property
    #End If
```

And your test works:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim p As TheParent
    Set p = New TheParent
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(p)
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

And now things seems to be OK. But...

Now, try to do something useful with Parent property of Child class, not only assure GC:

Slightly modified Parent Class; Child class the same:

```
 Option Explicit
Private Type tTheParent
    Child As TheChild
    CollectionName As String
End Type
Private this As tTheParent

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Child = New TheChild
    Set this.Child.Parent = Me
    Debug.Print this.Child.Parent.CollectionName
End Sub
Public Property Get GetChild() As TheChild
    Set GetChild = this.Child
End Property
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.Child = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get CollectionName() As String
    CollectionName = IIf(this.CollectionName = vbNullString, "COLLECTION", this.CollectionName)
End Property
```

New Test:

```
 Public Sub TestChildParent()
    Dim p As TheParent
    Set p = New TheParent
    Dim c As TheChild
    Set c = p.GetChild
    Debug.Print c.Parent.CollectionName
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(p)
    
    Set p = Nothing
 End Sub
```

And what we get? I crashed Excel, Word and the Video driver!

And now the @this's comment shines; now I got illuminated by his (this?) words:

> Please don't hard-code the size... ever. LenB is to VBA what sizeof is
> to C. Use it to size the allocation for the copy memory API. – this

I was directed here because yesterday I [posted at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943510/trying-to-reverse-objptr-to-an-object-im-getting-kernel-not-found-error-53-in-6?noredirect=1#comment107823007_60943510) an error 53 getting kernel, and until I crash windows I didn't understood that the correct Bruce McKinney's code for getting an Object from the object pointer is:

```
Dim objT As Object
CopyMemory objT, this.Address, LenB(this.Address) 'not 4
Set IWeakReference_Object = objT
CopyMemory objT, 0&, LenB(this.Address) 'not 4
```

And this answer my question at SO too, because the kernel 53 error gone...

PS: Please, don't be surprised at this enigmatic approach using this as Private Type

someone that I follow teached me ;)

PS2: And this, thanks for that! sorry, couldn't hold myself

Comment: This works, but not for the reasons you think it does. `#If Win64` checks whether the host application is 64-bit, true. However `LongPtr` automatically maps to `LongLong` on a 64-bit VBA instance anyway, so there is no need to check manually. You could remove the conditional compilation entirely! The only thing you might want to do to ensure robustness is to replace `Win64` with `VBA7` - `LongPtr` and `PtrSafe` weren't defined pre-VBA7 so you need to use long as you have done (don't worry about `LongLong` - there are no pre-VBA7 64-bit hosts so `Long` will always be big enough for the pointer)

Comment: *_"remove the conditional compilation entirely"_ and just use `LongPtr` for all the pointers, so get rid of your declarations that use plain `Long`. Incidentally, `cbCopy` does not need to be declared as `LongPtr` even in a 64-bit environment since it is _not a pointer_ but a count of bytes to copy, and that count is a `Long` on 32 _and_ 64 bit machines. Both will work because of the way memory is layed out - it's generally ok to pass a wider integer to an API function (`LongLong` instead of `Long`) because the function will just read only lower bytes. But not always and it's a bad habit IMO

Comment: @Greedo: Thanks, I'll try that - but first I have to get again a 32 bits VBE to test; in few days I think I can have it, and I will update here.

Comment: Sorry, just realised my last point is incorrect; cbCopy is declared as [`Size_T`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#size-t) which is an alias for `ULONG_PTR` - and so we should use `LongPtr` to represent it in VBA code as you have done. I think I'll write a separate answer on this stuff

Comment: @greedo, ok. I'm still on the process of clean off dust of my 10 yo 32 bits notebook to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, thank you, thank you!!  I have been tortured by this very problem and never could figure out why.

I would simplify the factory by storing the Object pointer and making the **IWeakReference_Object** the default member of the class.

Returning a self reference is great for creating anonymous classes. But I think that it is overkill for this here because I can't think of a scenario where it would be used outside of the Create method.  Basically, you are adding 3 lines of code to save one.  That being said, If add it to one class I will usually added it to all my classes for consistency.

### WeakReference:Class

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Option Explicit
Implements IWeakReference

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
#End If

Public hValue As Long

Private Property Get IWeakReference_Object() As Object
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
' Bruce McKinney's code for getting an Object from the object pointer:
    Dim objT As Object
    CopyMemory objT, hwnd, 4
    Set IWeakReference_Object = objT
    CopyMemory objT, 0&, 4
End Property

Public Function Create(value As Object) As WeakReference
    Dim ref As New WeakReference
    ref.hValue = ObjPtr(value)
    Set Create = ref
End Function
```

### TheChild:Class

```
Private ref As WeakReference

Public Property Get Parent() As TheParent
    Set Parent = ref
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal value As TheParent)
    Set ref = WeakReference.Create(value)
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print TypeName(Me)
    Set ref = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

### Alternate Approach

Here I just store the pointer handle (hwnd) of the objects and have a factory create weak referenced objects from the handles.  The advantage of this approach is that you only need to import a single class into your project.

That being said, the Interface does seem like a more natural fit.  If the VBA supported packages I would go with use the IWeakReference Interface.

### ObjectFactory:Class

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
#End If

Function getObjectHwnd(Object As Object) As Long
    getObjectHwnd = ObjPtr(Object)
End Function

Function getObject(hwnd As Long) As Object
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
' Bruce McKinney's code for getting an Object from the object pointer:
    Dim objT As Object
    CopyMemory objT, hwnd, 4
    Set getObject = objT
    CopyMemory objT, 0&, 4
End Function
```

### Child:Class

```
Option Explicit

Private hParent As Long

Public Property Get Parent() As TheParent
    Set Parent = ObjectFactory.getObject(hParent)
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal value As TheParent)
    hParent = ObjectFactory.getObjectHwnd(value)
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print TypeName(Me), Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Self` getter is never needed, indeed - I wouldn't call it *overkill* though: I do consistently use it in every single class that has a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True` and that exposes a factory method - and every time, the only method that uses the `Self` getter is the factory method... It's becoming a habit to always write my `Create` methods with `With New ClassName...Set Create = .Self...End With` - besides it's never exposed on whatever interface the class implements, so... really just a "convenience" member to facilitate the `With New` syntax

Comment: Not sure I like the "alternative approach" there though: it seems to defeat the purpose of the abstraction, by making the client code store a handle to the parent object, vs storing a reference to an `IWeakReference` instance.

Comment: The use of `IWeakReference` in [Battleship MVC Architecture] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202851/battleship-mvc-architecture) is really nice.  Aesthetically, it is much nicer than storing the handles.  I would still make `Object` the default member of the class. I just prefer `Set ViewEvents = adapter` over Set ViewEvents = adapter.Object.

Comment: I guess it would be idiomatic, yeah. IMO default members are a language trap though: code isn't just written to be executed; it's mostly written to be *read*, and default members abstracts away *the syntax* rather than *the idea*. This can easily makes the reader miss what's going on... the code says one thing, and does another behind your back -- unless you *know* the API and you're familiar with it *now*.. If only there was a VBIDE add-in that could warn you about implicit member access! A good chunk of VBA questions on SO are asked because of them, and solved with explicit member access ;-)

Comment: Default members if a Class can definitely by a trap.  However,  in the VBA, providing access to the default members is an intrinsic feature  of an Interface.  Seeing `position as IGridCood` for the first time, I would 
assume that it has `X` and  `Y` members.  I would also assume that I could use `position.X`.   `position.Object.X` on the other hand not so much.

Comment: On the flip side consider the `OLEObject`.  A good chunk of the questions on SO are asked because the actual `MSForms` object is accessed stored in `OLEObject.Object`.

Comment: With `Object` as a default member you'd be *writing* code that invokes the `RtlMoveMemory` logic for every single member access, while *reading like code that doesn't*... in this particular case, I'd much rather heavily encourage usage that makes this call explicit, or the object reference be held in a `With` block if it's going to be successively dereferenced for member calls. And then yep, `OLEObject` ;-p

Comment: TBH a few years ago I would probably have said that default members are in the language for a reason, we might as well use them, they're convenient, nothing wrong with them... C# has corrupted me!